# How to use a global variable that is visible by both HTML/Razor and javascript all on the same page

Tags: javascript, html, razor, global-variables

Here is my layout

```
<html>
@{ bool isAdmin = true; }

if(isAdmin)
{
//the breakpoint hits here
}
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">
function someFunction()
{
if(isAdmin){ //my breakpoint doesnt hit here}
}
$(document).ready(function()
{
 @if(isAdmin){ //my breakpoint hits here}
somefunction();
}   
</script>
```

How is it that my global variable is visible from the html/razor within the html and also within the javascript, yet it cannot be seen from the function within the javascript. This doesnt make sense to me. Also if i try something like adding @isAdmin to the function parameter, the error i get is "True is undefined", if i .ToLower() "True", the error is "unexpected token true"

Comment: Does your someFunction() ever get called?

Comment: yes it is a return someFunction() within document ready

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the second breakpoint hits is because the razor engine recognizes the `@if`, so your `isAdmin` is used properly. It appears that using `@isAdmin` in the JavaScript section will attempt to use the value of your variable as an identifier for a JavaScript variable (I'm not sure if this is really what's happening. After some testing, this appears to be the case; hence, "[value of your variable] is not defined."). Two ways you can get around this:

1. While writing regular JS, take your `isAdmin` value as a string, and convert to bool. `if (!!"@isAdmin")`
2. Use this syntax to go from razor to JS:

   `@if (isAdmin) //razor here
   {
     @:console.log('hello!') //@: causes the line to be interpreted as JS.
   }`

Comment: Awesome, so i was able to do if ("@isAdmin" == "True") within my function and it hit the breakpoint. Thanks.

Comment: I suppose I was lacking that case. I never liked comparing to the string version of a bool, though. Not that `!!"@isAdmin"` looks much better.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you call your function

```
<html>
@{ bool isAdmin = true; }

if(isAdmin) {
//the breakpoint hits here
}
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">
function someFunction() {
    if(isAdmin){ //my breakpoint doesnt hit here }
}
$(document).ready(function() {
   @if(isAdmin){ //my breakpoint hits here}
});
someFunction();
</script>
```

Comment: yes the function gets called within document ready, let me adjust code